# Printing pairs of keys and values based on conditional filtering

Tags: javascript

I am working on a pdf, which is generated with jspdf. For this I created an array first, which reflects the inputs in my interface:

```
let itemNew = [
 { index:'Kosten für Stories:',id: `${storiesNumber.value} Stories für ${storiesCosts.value} € monatlich` },
 { index:'Kosten für Posts:',id: `${postsNumber.value} Posts für ${postsCosts.value} € monatlich` },
 { index:'Kosten für Reels:',id: `${reelsNumber.value} Reels für ${reelsCosts.value} € monatlich` },
 { index:'Kosten für Bio:',id: `${bioCosts.value} € einmalig `},
 { index:'Redaktionsplan:',id: `${redaktionsplanCosts.value} € einmalig `},
 { index:'Monatliche Auswertung:',id: `${auswertungCosts.value} € einmalig `},
]
```

As those inputs are not required by default, some of them will can stay empty when the user hits the "Generate Pdf" button. The empty inputs should not be rendered into pdf. For this I need to filter those out somehow and link the code above with code below

```
itemNew.forEach(element => {
 arr = [Number(storiesNumber.value), Number(postsNumber.value), Number(reelsNumber.value),  Number(bioCosts.value), Number(redaktionsplanCosts.value), Number(auswertungCosts.value)]
 arr.filter(Boolean)
 var temp = [element.index,element.id];
 rows.push(temp);
});
```

I am aware, that for now those are two bits of code, not really connected to each other. What I try to achive is that, when `Number(storiesNumber.value) == false, { index:'Kosten für Stories:',id:` ${storiesNumber.value} Stories für ${storiesCosts.value} € monatlich `}` won't get pushed into row.

Comment: So, if all `values` are falsey, you want to skip those elements, right?

Comment: Exactly. Only true elements should be pushed. But elements of itemNew are not being proved at the moment, only the ones in arr. I am missing the connection here

Comment: What about when few `values` are falsey? Ex if `storiesNumber.value` is falsey, what should be the output?

Comment: If several values are falsey, they should be all ignored for rendering, meaning, rows should only contain true values

Comment: You can try this `items = [Number(storiesNumber.value), Number(postsNumber.value), Number(reelsNumber.value),  Number(bioCosts.value), Number(redaktionsplanCosts.value), Number(auswertungCosts.value)]
const rows = itemNew.reduce((res, element, index) => {
 if(items[index]) {
    res.push([index, element.id]);
}
 return res;
}, []); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter and map after to get the result you want.

```js
const storiesNumber = { value: "" };
const storiesCosts = { value: "" };
const postsNumber = { value: "" };
const postsCosts = { value: "" };
const reelsNumber = { value: "" };
const reelsCosts = { value: "" };
const bioCosts = { value: "" };
const redaktionsplanCosts = { value: "" };
const auswertungCosts = { value: "" };

let itemNew = [
  {
    index: "Kosten für Stories:",
    id: `${storiesNumber.value} Stories für ${storiesCosts.value} € monatlich`,
  },
  {
    index: "Kosten für Posts:",
    id: `${postsNumber.value} Posts für ${postsCosts.value} € monatlich`,
  },
  {
    index: "Kosten für Reels:",
    id: `${reelsNumber.value} Reels für ${reelsCosts.value} € monatlich`,
  },
  { index: "Kosten für Bio:", id: `${bioCosts.value} € einmalig ` },
  { index: "Redaktionsplan:", id: `${redaktionsplanCosts.value} € einmalig ` },
  {
    index: "Monatliche Auswertung:",
    id: `${auswertungCosts.value} € einmalig `,
  },
];

arr = [
  Number(storiesNumber.value),
  Number(postsNumber.value),
  Number(reelsNumber.value),
  Number(bioCosts.value),
  Number(redaktionsplanCosts.value),
  Number(auswertungCosts.value),
];

const row= itemNew.filter((_, i) => arr[i] !== 0).map(x => [x.index, x.id]);

console.log(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

[.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) does not modify the original array. It returns your filtered array.

Since you are already constructing `arr` array in the correct order, you can use it. Use `index` in the filter function to filter your `itemNew` array.

```
let arr = [Number(storiesNumber.value), Number(postsNumber.value), Number(reelsNumber.value),  Number(bioCosts.value), Number(redaktionsplanCosts.value), Number(auswertungCosts.value)]

let ans = itemNew.filter((x,index)=>{
  return arr[index] == 0;
}).forEach(y => { rows.push([y.index,y.id]) });
```

Comment: I still need to push true values into rows (var temp = [element.index,element.id]; rows.push(temp);) in which place should this happen?

Comment: Apologies. I have edited the answer now. Since you have the filtered array now, you can pass all of them into rows using forEach.